# How can I invoke a firebase storage function locally and manually?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am fairly familiar with invoking firebase firestore functions manually for testing. I have done this in the past with the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing). In short I make a wrappedOnWrite variable, assign it to my admin sdk.wrap(my firebase function), and then I invoke it with an object that represents the firestore collection before and after the call. Example:

```
const testEnv = functions({ projectId: **** }, '****');

      let wrappedOnWrite:
            | WrappedScheduledFunction
            | WrappedFunction<Change<QueryDocumentSnapshot>>;
    
       beforeAll(() => {
            // wrap the firebase function, ready to be invoked
            wrappedOnWrite = testEnv.wrap(moderateCompetition);
        });

 const changeDoc: Change<QueryDocumentSnapshot> = {
        before: testEnv.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot(dataBefore, path),
        after: testEnv.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot(dataAfter, path),
    };

    // call firebase function with the changes inputted to the function
    await wrappedOnWrite(changeDoc);
```

This is great for testing my firestore collections with jest, however, I am never seen this done with firebase storage, and I haven't been able to find many useful resources either. I have a pretty basic firestore .onFinalize function for storage:

```
export const blurImages = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {}
```

Is there any way to manually test it like in the example I gave above? When I initially deployed the function, it ran recursively and charged my company a couple of dollars, and I need to be able to run it periodically so that recession doesn't happen on the live function. Thanks in advance :)